chipgroup - firebase database - java
I have a cuisine category in my Firebase Realtime Database for every restaurant.
restaurant 1  cuisine : Italian . restaurant2 cuisine :fast food
how can I get all cuisine from Firebase Realtime Database and create a chip in the chip group with the same name?
I tried to do that but when I have 2 restaurants with the same cuisine, the chip group creates 2 chips with the same name. I tried Hashset but nothing changed.
or is there any way to create a chip group with 15 chips and hide those chips their name does not exist in any restaurant cuisine.
for example, if no restaurant has quisine :Italian , that chip with the name Italian was not visible in chipg roup.
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("resturants");

Query query = reference.orderByChild("cuisine");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (ds.getValue() != null){
                String restaurant_cuisine = String.valueOf(ds.child("cuisine").getValue());

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(restaurant_cuisine);
                HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
                hashSet.addAll(list);
                for (String string :hashSet){
                    Chip chip = new Chip(mContext);
                    chip.setText(string);
                    chipgroup.addView(chip);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});


With Realtime Database, the only way you can find out of some data is absent is to query all the places where the absent data could possibly be present (that is, all of the restaurants), then check all of them individually to see what's missing.  There is a not a simple query to do this.

is there any link or tutorial where I can read and understand better ? @Frank van Puffelen

When you're using the following query:
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("resturants");
Query query = reference.orderByChild("cuisine");

It means that you are reading all restaurants within the "restaurants" node and you order them according to the "cuisine" field. This means that if you have two restaurants that share the same "cuisine" name, then indeed you get two records. Since you get two restaurants for a specific cuisine, then two chips will be generated. Unfortunately, there is no way in the Firebase Realtime Database you can get only a single record of a specific type. Please note that there is no SELECT DISTINCT statement in the NoSQL database queries.
So in such cases, I recommend you create an additional node, to store only the chip names:
db
|
--- chips
     |
     --- italian: true
     |
     --- fastFood: true

Where the key is the "cuisine" name, while the value is the boolean true. This means that you have to manage this node separately, which also means that each time a new restaurant with a new type of cuisine is added, add the name of the cuisine here. The same is true if the name of the cuisine is deleted or updated.
Because the keys are unique, then you can read all these keys and create chips. In such a case there will be no duplicates at all. So you'll have a list of unique "cuisine" chips. Since it's a list, if you want to display, for example, all restaurants of a specific cuisine, then you have to track the user selection and perform the query that looks like this:
String userSelection = "italian"
Query queryByCuisine = query.equalTo("cuisine", userSelection);


yes thanks . it helped me a lot . is there any way to have multiple filter? for example 1:cuisine: Italian  2: seating: outdoor . so if I have  2 different chip group, how can I get data and show the result ?

@AlmaN Yes, you can chain as many .equalTo() as you need. So can I help you with other information?

equal.to() let me filter by only one child .I would like to filter with 2 child in same time when 2 chip group is checked .

Yes, you can chain multiple .equalTo() calls like this query.equalTo("cuisine", "Italian").equalTo("seating", "outdoor");. Give it a try and tell me if it works.
